# Best database for array like collections

Tags: database-recommendation

I'm going to build a Go application that will check id(s) in a list of ids. Structure will be something like this for database:

### Company A

List 1 -> 100.000 ids

List 2 -> 250.000 ids

### Company B

List 1 -> 100.000 ids

List 2 -> 250.000 ids

etc..

These ids will be strings and I need to efficently query multiple ids and get which are those exists in the collection. Write operation will be only once for each list so write performance isn't really important but read should be fast. What would be the best database solution for this on?

Answer (score 1):

> Best database for array like collections

No such thing, all modern databases are relatively equal in performance.

> What would be the best database solution for this

The best database **solution** would be to normalize your data and store it as rows in a table that relates the `List` objects to your `Company` objects. Then you can leverage proper indexing, and native querying methodologies. How you architect your database is what matters when it comes to performance.

Answer (score -2):

I think a **Key-Value** database is what you are looking for:

[image]

You are not looking for relations so I would drop any RDBMS database.

You want to search in a pool of data and match a criteria so I would rater go for a NoSQL engine.

Comment: The `List` object implicitly relates to the `Company` object. Storing the values from the `List` in a key-value store is not materially different than storing them as rows in a table, for OP's purposes.